# How to distribute data in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data as follows - ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

I am coping these data into google sheet - resultant will be - all the data will be copied in one cell.

### Cell01

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

**How i can distribute data in a way that each cell contains one alphabet?**

### cell01 | cell02 | cell03 | cell04 | cell05 | cell06 |cell07 | cell08 | cell09 | cell10 |cell11

A    |  B     |    C   |   D    |   E    |    F   |   G   |    H   |   I    |    J   |   H

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

With the ABC... string in cell A1, use this in column A of a free row:

```
=split(regexreplace(A1, "(.)", "$1µ"), "µ")
```